# How can I enable dark mode on Firefox on Windows 7 so that the settings page has a dark mode?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, firefox-extensions

How can I enable dark mode on Firefox on Windows 7 so that the settings page (`about:preferences#home`) has a dark mode?

---

I unsuccessfully tried:

- using the [Dark Reader](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/darkreader/?src=search) Firefox extension.
- using Firefox' native dark mode (customize -> themes -> dark)

The settings page:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Great answer by [Backseat-Driver](https://www.reddit.com/user/Backseat-Driver) on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/g6zfhe/how_can_i_enable_dark_mode_on_firefox_on_windows/foe8v6t/):

> You can tell Firefox that you want dark mode by adding `ui.systemUsesDarkTheme` [*number*] in `about:config` and setting the value to `1`.
>
> - 0: light
> - 1: dark
> - 2: no-preference
>
> Any other value and Firefox will use light.

[image]

[image]

Tested with Firefox 75.0 64-bit on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: This also changes how CSS dark mode on normal pages work (which is probably what you want if you are interested in dark mode)

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to settings at the top right corner.
2. Click customize.
3. Click Themes.
4. Select dark.
5. Click the ready button on the right down corner.

The settings page at about:preferences#home will remain the same.

Comment: Thanks, I tried but the settings page is still white. Is it dark on your side?

Comment: Yes, I will upload a video on how to do it in a few minutes. Can you wait until then?

Comment: If you are doing the same as in the video, but the result is not the same, can you please upload a picture of what do you want in your favourite host(like dropbox.com) and post it here.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tU8DhDvZiKU

Comment: Thanks, after enabling Firefox' native dark mode (customize -> themes -> dark as instructed in your video), does your settings page (`about:preferences#home`) have a dark mode?

Comment: No, the settings page remains the same. Is it that important that exactly the settings page changes, I don't think firefox allows that.

Comment: I found a way: https://superuser.com/a/1545481/116475