# How can I enable dark mode on Firefox on Windows 7 so that a webpage being loaded is dark and not white?

Tags: windows, firefox, firefox-extensions

How can I enable dark mode on Firefox on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate so that a webpage being loaded is dark and not white?

Example showing the issue: https://youtu.be/eh-DqoF1_m8

---

I unsuccessfully tried:

- [adding `ui.systemUsesDarkTheme` [*number*] in `about:config` and setting the value to `1`.](https://superuser.com/a/1545481/116475)
- using the [Dark Reader](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/darkreader/?src=search) Firefox extension.
- using Firefox' native dark mode (customize -> themes -> dark)

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- [Quora](https://qr.ae/pNrmm7)
- [Reddit](https://redd.it/g92567)

Comment: Franck I recommended firefox because this issue is possible to mitigate in firefox. Please visit this link and tell if this worked for you - https://amp.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/6s2l0w/removing_the_white_flash_before_a_page_loads/dl9t14q/

Comment: @BhavyaGupta Thanks, I have just tried, it doesn't seem to work.